# What model.predict() in Keras or Tensorflow is doing numerically?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

**What I would like to know:**

I have built and trained a CNN model in keras and have been able to calculate predictions, but I would like to know the details of the process of what is happening numerically in the prediction step.

**What I tried:**

(1) Calculate the score with the trained Keras model.

(2) Coded my CNN and calculated the score and compared it with (1) (→ discrepancy).

(3) Checked the source code of Keras and Tensorflow on GitHub and investigated the difference between predict() of Keras and my CNN in terms of numerical processing.

I built such a model in keras.

```
model = Sequential()
mode.add(Conv2D(20,kernel_size=(1,5), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', input_shape=(24,13,1), activation='relu'))
mode.add(Conv2D(20,kernel_size=(1,9), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
mode.add(Conv2D(20,kernel_size=(24,1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
mode.add(Flatten())
mode.add(Dense(20,activation='relu'))
mode.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
model.load_weights(model_path / '[model_filename].h5')
model.summary()
```

On the other hand, I created my predictive CNN code this way.
I omit the code but I have succeeded in getting the values of kernel and bias.

my CNN code(only dense and Convolution)

```
def mydense(ind, ker, bia, func):
  tem_dense = np.dot(ker.T, ind) + bia
  return func(tem_dense)

def myconv(ind, ker, bia, func):

  # input sample data's shape 
  H = ind.shape[0]
  W = ind.shape[1]

  # kernel' shape
  Hf = ker.shape[0]
  Wf = ker.shape[1]
  K = ker.shape[3]

  # result of convolution
  u = np.zeros((H - Hf + 1, W - Wf + 1, K))
  # output
  z = np.zeros((u.shape))
  
  for k in range(0,K):
    for n in range(0,W - Wf + 1):
      for m in range(0, H - Hf + 1):
        u[m,n,k] = (ind[m:m+Hf, n:n+Wf, :] * ker[:,:,:,k] + bia[k]).sum()

  z = np.array([func(i) for i in u])

  return z
```

The results are very different from model.predict().

**What I have already looked into:**

I have looked further at predict() and other source code, but I needed help from those in the know.

As in the convolution process (Conv2D or Conv), I would like to know in detail what is happening numerically in the Dense process as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your question is way, way too long

Comment: Thank you. I have made the correction. It would be very helpful if you could tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself.
I was mistaken and it was handled as per the text.
It didn't look like keras was doing anything else.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33266165)